# How to enable auto-completion in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I want to use autocomplete but it doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmb93.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIoyF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your IDE. The Arduino IDE 2+ comes equipped with this tool. the last version is available on [Arduino.cc](https://Arduino.cc) website.

Comment: those are IDE 2 screenshots

Comment: What is your OS?